# ASP.NET Windows Authentication Issues - Can't get site to accept my windows user and password

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.NET web site set up to use windows authentication (not sure if I'll be doing that again!).

If I use the following, I get access to the web site fine. I know that Windows auth is set up for the web site, and enabled in IIS.

```
<authorization>

    <allow users="*"/>

</authorization>
```

However, I don't want this site to be publicly accessible, so I use the following to grant access to a single user. I just get bounced for 3 attempts until I hit the error screen "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials."

Obviously the first question is - is the username, PC name correct... it is and I have tried every possible permutation. This worked fine on my previous dev box, and this new one is set up exactly the same.

```
<authorization>

    <allow users="PCNAME\MYUSER"/>
    <deny users="*"/>

</authorization>
```

ASP.NET logs don't offer any insight.

**UPDATE:** I've just seen from my past notes that I have had this issue before. Authentication does actuall work as long as I'm not on the host PC.

Why is this? I can't believe I've wasted so much time on this again.....!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just seen from my past notes that I have had this issue before. Authentication does actuall work as long as I'm not on the host PC.